# Creating DLL that contains a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a new WPF-Project. After creating the project, I changed the project properties to **outputtype = classlibrary**.

Here is my file structure:

[image]

The `CustomWindow.xaml` is a ResourceDictionary which discribes the appearance of the `CustomWindow.cs`. 
The file `CustomWindow.xaml` looks like

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="WpfApplication1.CustomWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

  <Style x:Key="MainWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <!-- ... -->  
     </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The class `CustomWindow.xaml` looks like

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class CustomWindow : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public CustomWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I added to the `App.xaml` following

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Common base theme -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/CustomWindow.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I changed the **property buildprocess of the file `CustomWindow.xaml` to `Page`**.

After that I build the lib. Now I want to use the style `MainWindow` for my new project's main window. I've added the lib to the project references. And to the `App.xaml` I added some lines of code:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Common base theme -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/CustomWindow.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I tried to build it, but I become two error's.
The first

> The resource "MainWindow" couldn't be find.

The second

> An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/CustomWindow.xaml".

Maybe someone of you got an idea.

Comment: It's possible the second error isn't a real error, and will disappear when you manage to compile. About `MainWindow`, I assume this error appears in CustomWindow.xaml?

Comment: The second error appears in my second project's `MainWindow.xaml` where I've added `Style={StaticResource MainWindow}`.

Both error only pop up in my second wpf application, where I want to use the .dll I've created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new **WPF User Control Library** project in Visual Studio.
2. Add a new ResourceDictionary to this project where you define your window style.
3. Add a reference to the **WPF User Control Library** Project from your **WPF application** project.
4. Modify the App.xaml file in the WPF Application project:

   ```
   <Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
                    StartupUri="Window9.xaml">
       <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <!-- Common base theme -->
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/CustomWindow.xaml" />
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Application.Resources>
   </Application>
   ```

"WpfControlLibrary1" is the name of the WPF User Control Library in the sample markup above and "CustomWindow" is the name of the resource dictionary in this project.

5. Set the Style property of your MainWindow in the WPF Application like this:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{StaticResource MainWindow}">
       <Grid>

       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```

Comment: Hey mm8. I need your help again. What is an **User Control Library**? There isn't any option to create a project like this. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 pro.

Comment: You should find the "WPF User Control Library" project template under File->New Project->Installed->Templates->Visual C#->Windows Desktop in VS 2013.

Comment: Okay.. I don't get it. Nevertheless, I will accept your answer.